# How to make leftjoin in laravel 5.4

Tags: mysql, join, laravel-5, left-join, right-to-left

I have two table 1)clients 2)orders. I trying to make leftjoin but I not getting correct result what i want. Please see image below.

Thanks

ClientController.php

```
$clients = Client::leftjoin('orders','orders.client_id','=','clients.id')
                    ->select(DB::raw("count(orders.id) as orderCount"),
                    'clients.name as name','clients.email as email',
                    'clients.phone as phone','clients.country as country',
                    'orders.total_amount')
                    ->where('orders.status',0)
                    ->get();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
   $myevents = DB::table('users')
        ->join('event_model_user', 'users.id', '=', 'event_model_user.user_id')
        ->rightJoin('events', 'event_model_user.event_model_id', '=', 'events.id')
        ->where('users.id','=',$user->id)
        ->orWhere('events.bookable','=',$user->zipcode)
        ->get();
```

this is an example of i used a right join to get the events where no user has done any booking!

in your case this would be something like (not tested)

```
 $myevents = DB::table('clients')
        ->leftJoin('orders','orders.client_id','=','clients.id')
        ->where('orders.status',0)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply. I have already use this query but i'm getting all rows. when i remove "->where('orders.status',0)" this line then return all rows. All rows needed.